# Can this nonlinear model be transformed to a linear one?

Tags: linear-model, nonlinear-regression

Consider the model

$$y=\frac{1}{1-\theta_1x^{\theta_2}}+\theta_3+\epsilon$$

(assume Gaussian iid errors, even though this is not relevant for the question). Is it possible to transform it into a linear one? I fiddled with it a bit, without success. Am I missing something, or is it just impossible to convert it to a linear model?

Comment: Do you mean linear in some function of $x$, linear in some function of $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$, or both?

Comment: @whuber I mean linear in the parameters, thus according to this definition $y=\beta_0+\beta_1\sin(x)$ would be linear but $y=\beta_0+\sin(\beta_1x)$ wouldn't. Transforming $x$ and $y$ to get to a linear model is ok. Ideally, I would also like to understand how the errors transform, since I'll have to fit the model to data, but let's say that for now the most urgent point is to understand whether this model is equivalent to a linear one or not.

Answer (score 4):

Using Taylor series with the [Lagrange explicit form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder),

$$
f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}x^2, (\xi \in [0, x]).
$$

If you apply this to the [geometric-series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Geometric_series) of $\frac{1}{1 - \theta_1x^{\theta_2}}$, and then apply on the result the [exponential function expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Exponential_function), it is easy to see that there is no possible form that is linear in $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. Otherwise, you would have two equivalent polynomials, where one has a nonzero $\theta_1 \theta_2$ term, but the other doesn't, which is impossible.

Comment: thanks, I was looking for a proof. UnfortunatelyI can't understand it :( I think the fastest/simplest solution would be to substitute the various links with the actual steps of your proof, making it self-contained. Anyway, I'll list my doubts. 1) If I'm not mistaken, you want to use the fact that two real polynomials are identical if and only if they have the same coefficients. I know this is true for polynomials of one variable and I guess it's true for multivariate polynomials, too. However, the Taylor formula with the Lagrange explicit formula of the remainder is not a polynomial...

Comment: ...because $\xi$ depends on $x$, so I don't understand why your argument holds. 2) You propose to use the geometric series expansion: does this mean you're making the substitution $z=\theta_1 x^{\theta_2}$ and then expanding $\frac{1}{1-z}$?

Comment: @DeltaIV Those are excellent points if you're after a more formal proof I'll try to answer tomorrow (pressed for time now).